# Spring Boot dockerfile configuration location argument not loading

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Im Developing a simple docker file for a spring boot war file.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG CONFIG_LOC=/app_config
RUN mkdir $CONFIG_LOC

COPY app_config/* $CONFIG_LOC/ 

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.war
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.war

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.config.location=/app_config","-Dspring.profiles.active=docker","-jar","/app.war"]
```

Some how the argument config location is not are not loading when running the spring application. So the spring application is not running.

Comment: Doesnt you need to copy the app_config folder into your war? You can try viewing the contents of your war file.

Comment: You can use WORKDIR instead of mkdir.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use these as arguments? Usually using something like `ARG CONFIG_LOC` means you're passing a value in your build command using `--build-arg`. Seems like in this build you should just use hard coded values. When running the application, any argument should be passed as an environment variable using the `-e` flag.